# How to get entire html code of a div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am developing an application in asp.net. In my web page (.aspx) I have multiple div. My requirement is getting entire html code of a particular div including the code of the specified div. How can I get that?

```
<div class="tab-pane" style="width: 348px; height: 204px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: none; display: block; position: relative; overflow: hidden; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);" id="back">
<div class="setLimit" style="width: 324px; height: 180px; margin: 12px; background-color: none; position: absolute; z-index: 51; overflow: visible;" id="safeZoneBack">
    <div id="customizePanelBack" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
        <div id="lblBack" style="position: absolute; background-color: none; text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: #000000; text-transform: none; overflow: hidden; z-index: 80; width: 324px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; top: 80px; left: 0px;">
            <label id="lbltextBack">Thank You</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="one" id="cutBackTop" style="background: url(images/dot-line.jpg) repeat-x; width: 100%; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: 6px; left: 0px;"></div>
<div class="two" id="cutBackBottom" style="background: url(images/dot-line.jpg) repeat-x; width: 100%; height: 1px; position: absolute; top: 197px; left: 0px;"></div>
<div class="three" id="cutBackLeft" style="background: url(images/dot-line.jpg) repeat-y; width: 1px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 6px;"></div>
<div class="four" id="cutBackRight" style="background: url(images/dot-line.jpg) repeat-y; width: 1px; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 341px;"></div>
```

For the above code I am writing the following code

```
var fronthtmlcode;
fronthtmlcode = $("#back").html();
alert(fronthtmlcode);
```

then it is only showing

```
<div class="setLimit" style="width: 324px; height: 180px; margin: 12px; background-color: none; position: absolute; z-index: 51; overflow: visible;" id="safeZoneBack">
<div id="customizePanelBack" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;">
    <div id="lblBack" style="position: absolute; background-color: none; text-align: center; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12pt; color: #000000; text-transform: none; overflow: hidden; z-index: 80; width: 324px; height: 20px; line-height: 20px; top: 80px; left: 0px;">
        <label id="lbltextBack">Thank You</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

not parent div code. Please help me.

Comment: Which is the the div content that you need? The code gives you the content from #back div and your question seems to be asking for the same.. please make the question more clear .. or may be you can add the div that you actually want as output

Comment: or do you seek the html including the div tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the div elements including the div:

```
var fronthtmlcode;
fronthtmlcode = $("#back").parent().html();
alert(fronthtmlcode);
```

Checkout this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zDH75/)

Please let me know if this was helpful or if you have any queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use outerHTML

```
fronthtmlcode = $("#back")[0].outerHTML;
```

Or use jQuery to get cross browser compatibility, You can take clone of the element you want and append it to some temporary container e.g. div. Now taking html of container div will give you the outer html of the element.

```
fronthtmlcode = $('<div></div>').append($('#back').clone()).html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the `outerHTML` of an entire element:

```
var fronthtmlcode;
fronthtmlcode = $( '<div/>' ).html( $("#back").html() ).html();
alert(fronthtmlcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                        var fronthtmlcode;
                        fronthtmlcode = $("#back").parent().html();
                        alert(fronthtmlcode);
                    });
                });
      </script>
```